# linker input file unused because linking not done with cython

Tags: python-3.x, c++17, cython

This is the setup for the installation of cython module:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name="online_no_mem",
    packages=find_packages(include=['.', '.*']),
    zip_safe=False,
    ext_modules=[
        Extension(
        "online_no_mem",
        sources=["online_no_mem.pyx"],
        extra_compile_args=[
            "libpheval.a",
            "-O3", "-std=c++17", "-fopenmp"],
        include_dirs=['../Nodes',
                      '/home/tomas/Desktop/Projects/thirdparty/HandEvaluator-master/cpp/include',
                      '/home/tomas/Desktop/Projects/MC'],
        language="c++",
    )],
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext}
)
```

During the compilation I have these errors:

```
tomas@tomas-tobefilledbyoem:~/Desktop/Projects/MC$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
skipping 'online_no_mem.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'online_no_mem' extension
gcc -pthread -B /home/tomas/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I../Nodes -I/home/tomas/Desktop/Projects/thirdparty/HandEvaluator-master/cpp/include -I/home/tomas/Desktop/Projects/MC -I/home/tomas/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c online_no_mem.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/online_no_mem.o libpheval.a -O3 -std=c++17 -fopenmp
cc1plus: warning: command-line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
gcc: warning: libpheval.a: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++ -pthread -B /home/tomas/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -pthread -shared -B /home/tomas/anaconda3/compiler_compat -L/home/tomas/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/tomas/anaconda3/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/online_no_mem.o -o /home/tomas/Desktop/Projects/MC/online_no_mem.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

And the error is:

```
>>> import online_no_mem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/tomas/Desktop/Projects/MC/online_no_mem.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: GOMP_critical_end
```

I believe the problem is the "libpheval.a" because if I remove the flag "-fopenmp" the error is: **undefined symbol: *ZN11phevaluator13EvaluateERKNS_4ES2_S2_S2_S2_S2_S2***

If I compile it as a normal c++ code with:

```
g++ online_no_mem.cpp -o online_no_mem.o libpheval.a -O3 -std=c++17 -I ../Nodes -I /home/tomas/Desktop/Projects/thirdparty/HandEvaluator-master/cpp/include -fopenmp
```

I have no problems.